# Material UI link to components in Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and Material-UI and I'm using both to build a simple portfolio. Right now, I have all my components put together on one page using `Grid`, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import About from './About';
import Resume from './Resume';

function MainView() {

  return (
    <div >
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Welcome></Welcome>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
          <About></About>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
          <Resume></Resume>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainView;
```

`Welcome` component has `Menu` component with Links to `About` and `Resume`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Menu() {

  return (
    <div >
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

However, when I click either of the links on the `Menu` it takes me to a new, separate page with `About` or `Resume` instead of scrolling down to those components in the grid and staying on the same page.
How can I organize this to be a single page with links to components? Is it possible to link to components in `Grid`? Or is putting all components in `Grid` not the right approach for what I want to do (a single-page app with linkable components)?

Here's my `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import About from './components/About';
import MainView from './components/MainView';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={MainView} />
          <Route exact path='/welcome' component={Welcome} />
          <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
          <Route exact path='/resume' component={Resume} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you specifically trying to have links that are like `/about`? You could always just make the link `#about` and put that ID on the header of the about section.

Comment: I did it and it worked! Thanks for offering a great simple solution!

Comment: Oh okay great. I was whipping up an example haha. Feel free to answer your own question. A few pointers since you're new to React: 1. you can delete those other routes now because the browser handles anchor links natively; 2. if you want a Grid item max width at all sizes, you can just define `xs` and leave the others off; 3. `<Welcome />` is shorthand for `<Welcome></Welcome>` in JSX